# Рисовать пиксель при условии

Tags: c#

В textbox есть строка, состоящая из 1 и 0. 
Код должен читать строку. Если 1, то в picturebox рисуется черный пиксель, иначе белый. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

пиксель закрашивается в черный цвет так:

`Graphics gr = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
gr.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1));`

а в белый вот так:

`Graphics gr = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
gr.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.White, 1), new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1));`

Comment: а как задать условие? я именно это не понимаю. определенное число из строки должно быть равно тому, что вы написали. и что означает "x, y"?

Comment: `Конверт.ТуИнт32(ТекстБокс.Текст);` :)